# Does a model have to be linked to another model or can it be linked to a table based on the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to debug a big application running on RoR. In my model `Text` I have this relation :

```
has_many :copies, :foreign_key => :original_id
```

does this mean that there must be another model in my app called Copie (should be Copy...) to which it is linked through the `foreign_key` or could it be just a link to another table which uses the same model `Text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, yes. There would be a `Copy` model. You can point it to a different model though, by using the `class_name` option

Usually, if it has a reference to a different table, the `class_name` keyword would have been used. For example: `has_many :copies, :class_name => 'YourOtherModel', :foreign_key => :original_id`

By convention, Rails assumes that the column used to hold the foreign key on the other model is the name of this model with the suffix _id added.

Rails does provide you with the ability to set the :foreign_key option directly:

See documentation [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-foreign-key)

You can also design a data model to have to relation to itself:

See documentation [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins)

I hope this provide you with some insight to further investigate

Comment: Actually I have this `:class_name => "Text"` in my model relation. For some reason I thought it wasn't relevant... So I have ```has_many :copies, :foreign_key => :original_id, :class_name => "Text"```

Comment: So `copies` will reference the `Text` table using 'original_id' as the foreign key

Comment: @Maxime consider upvoting the answer if you found it useful at all

Comment: I can't upvote yet as my reputation is only 9... But I will as soon as I can, your answer was useful indeed.

Comment: Glad it helped. You should be able to accept the answer